# Binding properties of an Object using MVVM and Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a PersonModel object which is populated with a single record of person by using a method call. This object has got 2 properties viz first name and last name. In the view I have two textboxes that is bound to FirstName and LastName properties. The binding is done in the format Person.FirstName and it bounds properly. I have a Text Block that is bound to FullName property ({Binding Path = FullName, Mode=OneWay}). But this is not displaying anything. Below is the extract of my view model code.

```
public PersonModel Person
{ 
    get { return _person; }
    set 
    { 
        _person = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Person);
    }
}

public string FirstName
{
   get  { return _firstName; }
   set
   {
     _firstName = value;
     NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstName);
     NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FullName);
   }
}

public string LastName
{
   get { return _lastName; }
   set
   {
     _lastName = value;
     NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LastName);
     NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FullName);
   }
 }

public string FullName
{
   get { return $"{ FirstName } { LastName }"; }
}
```

Comment: Nobody can possibly answer your question without guessing what code you have.

Comment: I have provided sample code. I can display First Name and Last Name using Person prefix like Person.FirstName. But now I cannot access any properties defined in the view model like for eg: Full Name - I know I can resolve this by defining this also in the Person class. But this does not solve my issue since I have other properties like for eg: disabling a button which is not going reflecting in the view. Looking forward for a solution.

Comment: Did you register the view model in the Bootstrapper class configure method?  container.PerRequest<MyViewModel>();

Comment: I hope I am not understanding your code incorrectly here, but it looks like you an instance of PersonModel within your PersonModel class and the binding is done with that instance. Is this intensional ? This results in you binding FirstName/LastName to one instance and FullName to a different instance of PersonModel.